# Segmentation fault when accessing string array of struct

Tags: c++, string

Im currently running into an issue where I have to input words (strings) into a binary search tree and am doing so by putting words(strings) into string arrays, however when I try to put it into the first element, it is segmentation faulting.

Here is what I have:

node.h

```
typedef struct Node{
    char letter;
    int asiccValue;
    struct Node *left, *right;
    string words[99];
    int wordCount;
}Node;
```

tree.cpp

```
// This function creates new nodes as needed
Node *createNode(string word){
    // Assigns values
    struct Node *temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->letter = word[0];
    temp->asiccValue = (int)word[0];
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->words[0] = word;
    temp->wordCount = 1;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: @TomKarzes I've adjusted that but getting the same error.

Comment: if `string` is actually `std::string` and this question is for the C++ programming language the answer will be radically different that it will be if `string` is a `typedef` and this is a C question. The crux would be under no circumstances should you `malloc` storage for `std::string` unless you're already an expert in C++ and would not need to ask this question. `malloc`ing `string`s requires special handling (search keyterm: placement `new`) because `malloc` only provides storage. It does not call constructors, and an unconstructed `string` is a timebomb..

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Fixed

Comment: @user4581301 have adjusted to be just a c++ question

Comment: Now that the tags are updated, are you permitted to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: @user4581301 yes

Comment: Turns out `vector` is unnecessary. `struct Node *temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));` doesn't know how to construct the 99 `string`s in the `word` member of `Node` (see comment above). You can solve this with `struct Node *temp = new Node;` `new` allocates storage for and then constructs a `Node`.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++, it leads to needless suffering.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` doesn't call constructors, meaning your `string` array isn't initialized.  For any non-trivial type, you really want to avoid `malloc` unless you know what you're doing (see also: placement `new`).

Using `new` should fix your problem.  Make sure you update existing code to use `delete` instead of `free`.  Also, consider getting rid of `new`/`delete` entirely, and using `make_unique` and friends.

```
Node *createNode(string word){
    // Assigns values
    Node * temp = new Node;
    temp->letter = word[0];
    temp->asiccValue = (int)word[0];
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->words[0] = word;
    temp->wordCount = 1;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: When using C++ you should avoid malloc as the memory is allocated in potentially different area than used by C++ programs that would normally use `new`. Mixxing dynamic memory allocation from different mechanism makes for potential issues.